# Retrieve table size and item count of multiple dynamo db tables using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I would like to know if it is possible to table size and item count of multiple dynamo database tables using boto3.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would write a loop to iterate over your tables, calling the boto3 method `describe_table` on [the DynamoDB client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#client).

In the response from each call you will extract the size of the table from the `TableSizeBytes` field, and the item count from the `ItemCount` field.